# how to have an int >255 in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sqldatatypes

I'm **very** new to SQL and know very little about it. But, I'm trying to add a column to each row so every user starts with 2000. I want this value to be an int so I'm using:

```
ALTER TABLE users
ADD amountChecking INT(2000);
```

and I get an error

> Error #1439 - display width out of range (max=255)

Comment: Display width. Int has a fixed size, but its display will never be longer than 255 digits.

Comment: Ok, so how can I make the value of ammountChecking 2000 on every row?

Comment: What you are setting is the number of digits, Set the DEFAULT to 2000 then it makes what you want

Comment: What database do you use(Oracle, MySQL, SQLServer or something else), also why do you want "I want this value to be an int" ?

Comment: I'm using the myphpadmin. I want each user that signs up to have 2000 "dollars".

Comment: That is not a database but ok, you have a table called users right? And to that table you want to add new column called "ammountChecking"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are using MySQL but if this is not working please comment so I can help more...

Try to do it like this:

Lets say you have a simple table that is created like this:

```
create table wp_usermeta (first_column int);
```

If you want to add new column to that table with datatype int you will do it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE wp_usermeta
ADD amountChecking int;
```

Then you will be able to add values 2000 in that table like this:

```
Insert into wp_usermeta values (2000, 2000);
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8596041af7a90f54aa1a5e8dc01beb30) and in this DEMO link you can see the results of this little experiment and play more to learn...

If you want to have a DEFAULT value of 2000 in this column when someone does not insert any data into it then you can use this:

```
ALTER TABLE wp_usermeta
ADD amountChecking int default 2000;
```

See this [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=000cfe94ba11073211f234304e6077d5) for the DEFAULT example.

And in your comment to your question you are asking:

> Ok, so how can I make the value of amountChecking 2000 on every row?

Then do this:

```
update wp_usermeta 
set amountChecking = 2000;
```

Check this [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=389828e2854113b83cd7a1c26b2d9d6c) to see how that works.

Comment: It worked! I had to change a few things to make it a default, so when each user signs up, they will have 2000 as their value. I really hate to bother you; but how can I fetch this value 2000 value from PHP to perhaps echo: you have "$ammountChecking" dollars.

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the concept of MySQL integer datatypes. The *width* (like `10` in `int(10)`) is not meaningful: it is barely an indication for clients of how many characters they should expect when displaying the concerned value.

[As explained in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html), the `int` datatype uses 4 bytes of storage: unsigned integers can store values in range [0, 4294967295], while signed integers cover range [-2147483648, 2147483647].

This should be more than enough to meet your requirements. I would even suggest to use a smaller integer storage, like `smallint` (2 bytes, up to 65535 if unsigned), or maybe `mediumint` (3 bytes, up to 16777215 unsigned). The importance of optimizing the storage is often under-estimated but sets for better scalability in the long run.